# Have a review task indicate if a question has been updated since its last close vote

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966336/relatively-new-to-java-programming-but-confused-with-android-studio/24966489?noredirect=1#comment38815744_24966489) which started out as a well-written two paragraph build up to a valid question (why don't Android apps have a `main` method). But the user also tacked on a one sentence off-topic question (which IDE is better).

By the time I got to it, it had six down-votes, two close votes, and no comments.

Then, after another user edited it to remove the off-topic question, it received another few down-votes and **several** more close votes for it being off-topic!

I think part of the purpose of down-votes is to prod users into fixing a question, after which it should not continue receiving down-votes for an obsolete issue.

But aside from that is the fact that reviewers kept coming by and voting to close it without even reading the question. I suspect that the first close votes came from people that read only the last sentence of the old post (kind of lazy), and the rest of them simply chose to agree with previous votes without checking if the previous votes should even apply (really lazy).

So my suggestion is that if a question has been updated since it received its last close vote, there should be a conspicuous notice at the top of the review page that says as much.

> **This question has been updated recently. Previous close votes may no longer apply.**

Comment: Received seven more close votes? That's not even possible. Did you mean to type something else there?

Comment: Side-note: that question is still quite broad, and a dupe of quite a few things: [How can Android source code not have a main method and still run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221467/how-can-android-source-code-not-have-a-main-method-and-still-run), [Where is main() in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293329/where-is-main-in-android), etc...

Comment: @animuson Don't know if I missed something. I could have sworn it said something like "on hold by ..." and had nine names listed.

Comment: @hichris123 You have good search skills. :) I spent a couple minutes trying to find a dupe before answering because I couldn't believe it hadn't been asked before, and failed. Most searches I did turned up pages of stuff containing the word main but unrelated.